# How to get Windows installed updates

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-update

I need to get all installed updates on Windows machine. I tried WUA API, but the result is differs from what I see in Control Panel - Installed Updates. My code returns 321 update, while in control panel I see 508. Here is my code:

```
IUpdateSearcher* updateSearcher = NULL;
IUpdateSession* updateSession = NULL;
IUpdateCollection* updateList = NULL;
ISearchResult* results = NULL;
IUpdate* updateItem = NULL;
BSTR criteria = NULL;
LONG updateSize = 0;
HRESULT hr;

if ((hr = CoInitialize(NULL)) != S_OK)
{
    return -1;
}
if ((hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UpdateSession, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUpdateSession, (LPVOID*)&updateSession)) != S_OK)
{
    return -1;
}
if ((hr = updateSession->CreateUpdateSearcher(&updateSearcher)) != S_OK)
{
    return -1;
}
if ((hr = updateSearcher->put_ServerSelection(ssWindowsUpdate)) != S_OK)
{
    return -1;
}

criteria = SysAllocString(L"IsInstalled=1 or IsInstalled=0 or IsHidden=1 or IsPresent=1");
if ((hr = updateSearcher->Search(criteria, &results)) == S_OK)
{
    std::wcout << L"[*]Successfully completed search for updates on this host" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::wcout << L"[-]Failed to search for updates" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

results->get_Updates(&updateList);
updateList->get_Count(&updateSize);
if (updateSize == 0)
{
    std::wcout << L"[-]No updates available for this host" << std::endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
std::set<std::wstring> KBs;
for (LONG i = 0; i < updateSize; i++)
{
    IStringCollection *KBCollection;
    LONG KBsSize = 0;
    updateList->get_Item(i, &updateItem);
    updateItem->get_KBArticleIDs(&KBCollection);
    KBCollection->get_Count(&KBsSize);

    for (LONG i = 0; i < KBsSize; i++)
    {
        BSTR KBValue;
        KBCollection->get_Item(i, &KBValue);
        std::wstring ws(KBValue, SysStringLen(KBValue));
        KBs.insert(ws);
    }
}


if ((hr = updateSearcher->put_ServerSelection(ssOthers)) != S_OK)
{
    return -1;
}
BSTR serviceID = SysAllocString(L"7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d");

if ((hr = updateSearcher->put_ServiceID(serviceID)) != S_OK)
{
    return -1;
}

hr = updateSearcher->Search(criteria, &results);
if ((hr = updateSearcher->Search(criteria, &results)) == S_OK)
{
    std::wcout << L"[*]Successfully completed search for updates on this host" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::wcout << L"[-]Failed to search for updates" << std::endl;
}

results->get_Updates(&updateList);
updateList->get_Count(&updateSize);
if (updateSize == 0)
{
    std::wcout << L"[-]No updates available for this host" << std::endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
for (LONG i = 0; i < updateSize; i++)
{
    IStringCollection *KBCollection;
    LONG KBsSize = 0;
    updateList->get_Item(i, &updateItem);
    updateItem->get_KBArticleIDs(&KBCollection);
    KBCollection->get_Count(&KBsSize);

    for (LONG i = 0; i < KBsSize; i++)
    {
        BSTR KBValue;
        KBCollection->get_Item(i, &KBValue);
        KBs.insert(KBValue);
    }
}

SysFreeString(criteria);
SysFreeString(serviceID);

CoUninitialize();

std::wcout << KBs.size() << std::endl;
```

Can anyone please explain how can I get all the updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WUA API only lists updates installed through Windows Updates Services.

To list other kind of updates you may use [Windows Installer API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369426(v=vs.85).aspx), specifically:

- [`MsiEnumPatchesEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370100(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [`MsiGetPatchInfoEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370128(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks. So my code should return only updates from Microsoft Windows section of Control Panel - Programs and Features - Installed Updates, right?

Comment: @rudolfninja It's not restricted to just Windows. Updates for other Microsoft products and some third party components like drivers may also be installed through Windows Update.

Comment: Thanks. I got you. One more question. Why my output is differs from wmic qfe get hotfixid output? WMI output has exact the same list as in  Microsoft Windows section of Control Panel - Programs and Features - Installed Updates. BTW, functions you mentioned helped to get other updates from control panel, but not that are in Microsoft Windows section. Now the only way I found to get all the updates from this section is WMI query. What is incorrect in my code?

Comment: @rudolfninja I have no clue. Maybe experiment with filter criteria in call to `updateSearcher->Search()`.

Comment: Yeah, WUA API is such crap (excuse my French). I feel like someone at MSFT just ordered to stop any development of it (because it's old) and the Windows UI team went their own way and get the installed updates in some secret under-the-hood way.